# Element calling old action after class change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `p` element that when i click i want to change the class of it (from A to B). I can see the class indeed changes but when i click the element it continues to call the action on A not on B.

I though it was because i was doing it dinamically but even using `on` i can't get this to work.

```
        <p class='a'>Class is A</p>

        $(".a").on("click", function(e){

            alert("A");
            $(this).removeClass("a");
            $(this).addClass("b");
            $(this).html("Changed to B");
        });

        $(".b").on("click", function(e){

            alert("B");

        });
```

Comment: You're binding the event handlers to the element, you're just using the classes to find the elements when the page is first loaded.

Comment: You need to use event delegation, `$(document).on("click", ".a", ...)`

Comment: @Barmar this question comes up a lot but I don't know of a good canonical dupe for it. Do you?

Comment: @chiliNUT What about the dup I used?

Comment: @Barmar ha, i didnt reload my page so I didnt see it yet.

Comment: I did a lot of research but i could not come up with the right terms to find what i needed. Thanks for the help Barmar, i can vote your awnser if you make one.